# Splitting string values in list into individual values, Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of values in which some values are words separated by commas, but are considered single strings as shown:

```
l = ["a",
     "b,c",
     "d,e,f"]

#end result should be
#new_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

I want to split those strings and was wondering if there's a one liner or something short to do such a mutation. So far what, I was thinking of just iterating through `l` and `.split(',')`-ing all the elements then merging, but that seems like it would take a while to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner using a (nested) list comprehension:

```
new_list = [item for csv in l for item in csv.split(',')]
```

See it run [here](https://repl.it/repls/MistyPinkWorkspaces).

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
new_list = list(itertools.chain(*[x.split(',') for x in l]))

print(new_list)
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of unusual but you could `join` all your elements with `,` and then `split` them:

```
l = ["a",
     "b,c",
     "d,e,f"]

newList = ','.join(l).split(',')
print(newList)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: I like this solution. It just takes a bit longer than the one liner posted by @Blorgbeard. Still a great solution though!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a one-liner, but 2 lines:

```
>>> l = ["a",
     "b,c",
     "d,e,f"]
>>> ll =[]
>>> [ll.extend(x.split(',')) for x in l]
[None, None, None]
>>> ll
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

The accumulator needs to be created separately since `x.split(',')` can not be unpacked inside a comprehension.